# can i add meshes together before sending to mesh filter unity c#

Tags: filter, unity-game-engine, mesh

this question is kind of general question in unity c#
i know i cant have more than one mesh filter 
but i am generating more that one mesh in a script and i wanted to have them all rendered at once in one object but i dont want to merge the vertices arrays so i can still delete faces on the fly

the basic idea is a voxel as one game object , but made of different faces by script 
i want to keep the faces accessibles without going inside a huge array

so now i kinda have 6 faces as meshes and i dont know how to render them

what is the best way to do this , / best way to go , / noob here

Answer (score 0):

so i have some kind of answer , but still need guidance on the conceptual approach 
so i rewrote my "voxel" but now i am thinking about writing a serie of functions to "destroy" faces if they re not needed , but the problem is , if i put my triangles (i thought it was the easiest) all to 0 0 0  , it is not like freeing any memory , it is just not visible , so it is not the good way to go

how would someone go to do some kind of optimized voxel ?

i guess that from my code you understand that i am a beginner

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))]
public class Voxel : MonoBehaviour {

public Vector3 position ;

const float V = 0.5f;
Vector3[] vertices ;
int[] triangles;
Vector2[] uv ;
Mesh mesh ;

void Start () {
    vertices = new Vector3[24];
    triangles = new int[36];
    uv = new Vector2[24];
    mesh = new Mesh();

    Front ();
    Right ();
    Back ();
    Left ();
    Top ();
    Bottom ();

    renderMesh ();
}
public void renderMesh(){
    mesh.Clear();
    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.triangles = triangles;
    mesh.uv = uv;
    mesh.Optimize();
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();

    MeshFilter mesh_filter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    MeshCollider mesh_collider = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
    mesh_filter.mesh = mesh;
    mesh_collider.sharedMesh = mesh;
}

public void Front(){
    vertices[0] = new Vector3(-V,V,-V);//fronttopleft
    vertices[1] = new Vector3(V,V,-V);//fronttopright
    vertices[2] = new Vector3(-V,-V,-V);//frontbottomleft
    vertices[3] = new Vector3(V,-V,-V);//frontbottomright
    triangles[0] = 0;//front polys
    triangles[1] = 1;
    triangles[2] = 3;
    triangles[3] = 0;
    triangles[4] = 3;
    triangles[5] = 2;
    uv[0] = new Vector2(0,1); 
    uv[1] = new Vector2(1,1);
    uv[2] = new Vector2(0,0);
    uv[3] = new Vector2(1,0);
}
public void Right(){
    vertices[4] = new Vector3(V,V,-V);
    vertices[5] = new Vector3(V,V,V);
    vertices[6] = new Vector3(V,-V,-V);
    vertices[7] = new Vector3(V,-V,V);
    triangles[6] = 4;
    triangles[7] = 5;
    triangles[8] = 7;
    triangles[9] = 4;
    triangles[10] = 7;
    triangles[11] = 6;
    uv[4] = new Vector2(0,1); 
    uv[5] = new Vector2(1,1);
    uv[6] = new Vector2(0,0);
    uv[7] = new Vector2(1,0);
}
public void Back(){
    vertices[8] = new Vector3(V,V,V);
    vertices[9] = new Vector3(-V,V,V);
    vertices[10] = new Vector3(V,-V,V);
    vertices[11] = new Vector3(-V,-V,V);
    triangles[12] = 8;
    triangles[13] = 9;
    triangles[14] = 11;
    triangles[15] = 8;
    triangles[16] = 11;
    triangles[17] = 10;
    uv[8] = new Vector2(0,1); 
    uv[9] = new Vector2(1,1);
    uv[10] = new Vector2(0,0);
    uv[11] = new Vector2(1,0);
}
public void Left(){
    vertices[12] = new Vector3(-V,V,V);
    vertices[13] = new Vector3(-V,V,-V);
    vertices[14] = new Vector3(-V,-V,V);
    vertices[15] = new Vector3(-V,-V,-V);
    triangles[18] = 12;
    triangles[19] = 13;
    triangles[20] = 15;
    triangles[21] = 12;
    triangles[22] = 15;
    triangles[23] = 14;
    uv[12] = new Vector2(0,1); 
    uv[13] = new Vector2(1,1);
    uv[14] = new Vector2(0,0);
    uv[15] = new Vector2(1,0);
}
public void Top(){
    vertices[16] = new Vector3(-V,V,V);
    vertices[17] = new Vector3(V,V,V);
    vertices[18] = new Vector3(-V,V,-V);
    vertices[19] = new Vector3(V,V,-V);
    triangles[24] = 16;
    triangles[25] = 17;
    triangles[26] = 19;
    triangles[27] = 16;
    triangles[28] = 19;
    triangles[29] = 18;
    uv[16] = new Vector2(0,1); 
    uv[17] = new Vector2(1,1);
    uv[18] = new Vector2(0,0);
    uv[19] = new Vector2(1,0);
}
public void Bottom(){
    vertices[20] = new Vector3(V,-V,V);
    vertices[21] = new Vector3(-V,-V,V);
    vertices[22] = new Vector3(V,-V,-V);
    vertices[23] = new Vector3(-V,-V,-V);
    triangles[30] = 20;
    triangles[31] = 21;
    triangles[32] = 23;
    triangles[33] = 20;
    triangles[34] = 23;
    triangles[35] = 22;
    uv[20] = new Vector2(0,1); 
    uv[21] = new Vector2(1,1);
    uv[22] = new Vector2(0,0);
    uv[23] = new Vector2(1,0);
}
```

}